# How to conduct multi-thread with task in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Do you have a better way to do multi-thread?

```
GenericLoad newload = new GenericLoad();

Task<IList<List<string>>> task1 = Task<IList<List<string>>>.Factory.StartNew(() => newload.Parse(CSVFile1, ','));
Task<IList<List<string>>> task2 = Task<IList<List<string>>>.Factory.StartNew(() => newload.Parse(CSVFile2, '|'));

task1.wait();
task2.wait();

PrintCSV(task1.Result);
PrintCSV(task2.Result);

task1.Dispose();
task2.Dispose();
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Can you edit your question to make it clear what you want the output to be?

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot wrong in this question, so much so that it would be impossible to go into every aspect. However, this is probably more what you are looking for

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
   var newload = new GenericLoad();

   var task1 = Task.Run(() => newload.Parse(CSVFile1, ','));
   var task2 = Task.Run(() => newload.Parse(CSVFile2, '|'));

   await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

   PrintCSV(task1.Result);
   PrintCSV(task2.Result);

}
```

It uses `async await`, `Task.Run`, `Task.WhenAll`. My advice is to do some research into all of these